# How to add whitespace when appending values extracted from txt file in python

Tags: python, split, append, whitespace, file-read

In a text file I have two columns of value (x and y)
The file was read and it was split using space and appended in x and y.
but while appending x values, it is continuous without any space.
How to add space or to make it appear in new line for every appended value.

```
import numpy as np 

x = []
y = []

for line in open('IV.txt', 'r'):
    lines = [i for i in line.split(" ")]
    x.append(lines[0])
    y.append(lines[1])

f1 = open('xdata.txt','a')
f1.writelines(x)
f1.close()

f2 = open('ydata.txt','a')
f2.writelines(y)
f2.close()
```

the input data is

```
0 3
0.2 3.4
0.4 3.6
0.6 3.8
0.8 4.2
1 5.3
1.2 5.5
1.4 5.8
1.6 6.0
1.8 6.4
2 6.8
2.2 7.1
2.4 7.8
2.6 8.2
2.8 8.4
3 8.8
```

So the output of x appears as
00.20.40.60.811.21.41.61.822.22.42.62.83

Comment: It appears you are expecting `writelines()` to insert line breaks between the rows of the list you give it. It doesn't. Do `x.append(lines[0]+"\n")` etc to put the line breaks in your data before output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
f.writelines(" ".join(x))
f.writelines("\n".join(x))
```

You can put space or newline like this.

**ADD**

you can get x, y array from input data like this.

```py
x = list()
y = list()
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        split_line = line.split()
        x.append(split_line[0])
        x.append(split_line[1])
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy these values to array

Comment: Actually from the input data, I need two arrays of x and y.

Comment: For that I tried extracting like this. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: I just updated my answer for get x, y array from input data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the lists? If not, I suggest to write directly to the files without appending to the lists. Also, I would use the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) instead of explicitly opening and closing the files. Since Python 3.10 we have [parenthesized context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html) that simplify code like the one you are trying to write with the following syntax.

```
with (
    open('IV.txt', 'r') as f,
    open('xdata.txt','w') as x,
    open('ydata.txt','w') as y,
):
    for line in f:
        _x, _y = line.split(' ')
        x.write(f'{_x}\n')
        y.write(f'{_y}\n')
```